# How to use CSS withinin the file - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to react. And I'm trying to learn some new stuff. So what I want to do is to add CSS within my Header.js file, And I don't know how to do that. Because I don't want to import external or inline CSS. But rather use it like in Html with  tag on the header. But not just that, I want to use that CSS specifically for the file, in this case, Header.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can create style object inside react component like this:

```js
const myDivStyles = {
   color: "red",
   fontSize: "32px"
}
```

All propertis are the same like in CSS but this one with "-" sign change in to camelCase nams, e.g. font-size change to fontSize, background-color change to backgroundColor.

Then you can add this style to elements in your components by **style** attribute.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={ myDivStles } />
    )
}
```

You can also describe style without creating style object like this:

```
<div style={{ color: "red", backgroundColor: "#fff" }} />
```

Be sure you are using double closure **{{ }}**.

**EDIT**
With :hover selector

You have two prosibilites. First you can use component state to determinate if component is hovered and then prepare correct style, e.g:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         hovered: false
      }
      this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this)
   }

   toggleHover(state) {
      this.setState({
        hovered: state
      })
   }

   render() {
      const styles = {
        color: this.state.hovered ? "red" : "blue"
      }

      return (
          <div style={styles} onMouseEnter={ () => this.toggleHover( true ) } onMouseLeave={ () => this.toggleHover( false ) }> 
              Text 
          </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Second you can use js styled components syntax and refer to other component, you can read more about this here: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

But to be honest when I dealing with :hover or other selectors I prefer using default css files or much more often scss files prepared for components. So when I have e.g Button component in same location I have Button.css ( or Button.scss ) file where I can work with standard css. After this I have css files connected with components which should handled them.

Comment: How can i use :hover thoo?

Comment: Check added "EDIT" section :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilites.

The simplest is to use `css` code directly in the element like

```
<div style={{color:'#000',backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
...
</div>
```

Or you can use the libraries for that, like `styled-components` (https://styled-components.com/) for this.
You need to import this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

Then you can define your element `css` on the top of the page, i.e. `SomeCSSStyling`

```
const SomeCSSStyling = styled.div`
   color:#000;
   background-color:#fff;
`
```

Then you can use this constant in the class code of the `react` component:

```
class MyReactComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SomeCSSStyling>
            ...
            </SomeCSSStyling>
        );
    }
}

export default MyReactComponent;
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also define `:hover` or `::before` etc. with `style-components`:

```
const SomeCSSStyling = styled.div`
   color:#000;
   background-color:#fff;

   &:hover{
      font-weight:bold;
   }
`
```

Comment: What about adding states such as :hover?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please see my update in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

This might help

Header.js

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    marginTop: Metrics.ratio(0),
    marginHorizontal: Metrics.ratio(70),
    fontFamily: Fonts.type.base,
    fontSize: Fonts.size.normal,
    color: Colors.black,
  },
});

class Header extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={ styles.color } />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to do this within the page, not having external files.